# Is it possible to access the post-lighting color associated with each fragment of an object in SceneKit with Swift?

Tags: swift, scenekit, vertex

Does anyone know how to access the color associated with each fragment of an object in SceneKit after lighting has been applied? I'd like to check the color of these to know which ones are lit and which are in the shadow of another object or facing away from a light source. I can access the color of each fragment with a shader, but I'd like to access it in Swift if possible.

EDIT: Apparently, fragment shaders run prior to ray tracing (which makes sense), so even in a shader I can't access the lighting information I'm looking for.

Comment: "ones are lit and which are in the shadow of another object or facing away from a light source." This underlying problem is totally different than the question in the title

Comment: This sounds to me like a ray tracing issue, where you check the light source using some shadow rays. Then, I might have some information to you. I think it is possible to fetch the raw color values from each vertex using swift, but getting the colors after the fragment shader has been run is related to GPU operations, and can only be accessed using metal, or probably SCNTechnique (as far as I know). Here is the Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71704052/metal-ray-tracing-scenekit-or-realitykit/

Comment: @ZAY I can access the per vertex color from Swift using the object's geometry, but, as you pointed out, light doesn't affect the color values. It looks like I'll need to  add ray tracing code in Metal.